# Overlay items are not accessible

Tags: vuejs2

I am creating a full screen navigation 
[image: Full screen navigation using background overlay]

This navigation is opening on a button click. The problem is that the `li`and `close` button are not accessible. I am not able to click on them.

Html

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <v-btn class="white--text closebtn" icon v-on:click.prevent="CloseDialog">
        <v-icon>cancel</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  z-index :99;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 55px;
    font-size: 80px;
    cursor :pointer
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

Javscript

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"
export default {
  computed: mapGetters({ isLoggedIn: 'CheckAuth', items: 'GetItems' }),
  data() {
    return {
      clipped: true,
      drawer: true,
      fixed: false,
      miniVariant: true,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
      title: 'Vuetify.js'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('ChangeAuth');
    },
    OpenDialog() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    },
    CloseDialog() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add the relevant JavaScript code to the question

Comment: Please check now I have added Js Code

Comment: I am using VuetifyJs css framework

Comment: Vuex is for state management, you still need to add the normal Vuejs code (On click events etc) for your object and not inside the Vuex for example the v-on:click

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure CSS issue. You can either add :after pseudo element and create the background with it. Or you can use `pointer-events: none;` 
CSS property on the overlay element.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But didn't resolve my problem :(

Comment: Can I see your app on codepen or jsfiddle. It's easy to fix but it strictly depends on your code structure.

Comment: thanks @El Damielo but I have changed my code entirely now